# Upgraded to xcode 4.6 - Local Git not available anymore

Tags: xcode, git, svn

xCode upgrade blues. The upgrade went fine and smooth except for Git. When I try to commit, I get this message:

> "The repository "project name" could not be reached. Please verify
>   that the repository is online and reachable and try again."

Here are some data points:
 1. I am running Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 (11G63)
 2. I downloaded xCode 4.6 from the file download list (versus app store) - just in case this is related to some keychain developer account or something
 3. I have been using a local git.
 4. The project name in the repository is now red after the xcode upgrade
 5. I can see everything on xcode repository except the branches, I don't even see "master". I also cannot add any branches (and obviously can't commit)
 6. I checked on terminal and my git is fine and I can see all the branches as well: command is "git branch"
 7. I tried the usual restart xCode/reboot with no avail.

Thanks

Comment: It happens to existing repository or to all repositories, even new?

Comment: And *where* is the remote repo?

Comment: @trojanfoe, there is no remote; just local.

Comment: @dig, it only happened to one repository (project). Nothing particular about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of headache, I found the problem:

In the directory chain to the repository, one of my folders had a name that contained a "/" forward slash:

> /Users/username/Desktop/.../directorynamewithforwardslash/project directory

That seems to have tripped the reestablishing of the gits after an xCode upgrade.

I changed the dir name (removed the "/") and it worked. I hope this helps someone.

thanks

Comment: Huh?  You can't have a slash in a filename, so how did it get there?

Comment: @trojanfoe, the slash was in folder name.

Comment: Sorry to be stupid, but where exactly is: the directory chain to the repository

Comment: @DoctorG, because this is a local Git, the directory chain is really just the directory of the project.